# To print a pattern like 1 , 1 22 , 1 22 333 using java

Tags: java

Could someone help me to print the following pattern using java

```
1
1 22
1 22 333
1 22 333 4444
```

Below is the code i have written

```
class output {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int i, j, num;
        for(i=1; i<5; i++){
            num=1;
            for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(num+ " ");
                num++;
                //System.out.print(j+1);
            }
            System.out.print(i++);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First you will want to split your code into string creation and into outputting. Next you will want to have a look at Java 8 Stream API.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class output {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, k;
        for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                for (k = 1; k <= j; k++) {
                    System.out.print(j);
                }
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
1 
1 22 
1 22 333 
1 22 333 4444
```

Comment: @vinu best way to thank is through accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class op {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lim = 10;
    for(int i=1 ; i<=lim;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            System.out.print(j);
            for(int k=1;k<j;k++){
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Sorry I did't see your post, I made a program and directly posted here.. lol yes and we have the same program :P